# What do I need to complete a Bitcoin bonus payment transaction?

Tags: transactions

It's my first time requesting payment for my Bitcoin bonus payment transactions, without information on my registration form. I've been trying to get my payment process completed transfer but stops in the ending of the transaction. How do I locate where the transfer is going? Or how do I receive and have it in my accounts?

Comment: Sounds like you are being scammed. This is not how bitcoin works.

Comment: Hi Adam, I have voted to close your question as a duplicate of the above question, because it sounds to me like you are in a similar situation as the asker on that topic. If I am mistaken, please let us know here on the topic either by editing your question post or a comment so we can help you reopen your topic. Welcome to Bitcoin Stack Exchange.